# How to make gnome-shell calendar open calendar app's event details when clicking onto calendar entry?

Tags: gnome3, gnome-shell, calendar, evolution

In gnome-shell's top bar, calendar items are shown. This is great. However, I miss the possibility to click onto an item and then see more details/or simply to be led to the specific event item in evolution or another preferred calendar application.

The missing functionality is this: `click on calendar item@top bar` --> `open default calendar's details about this calendar item`.

Is it configurable, and if yes how, to make gnome-shell calendar open a specific calendar app when clicking onto a calendar item?

Comment: If someone can make a widget to launch a default calendar app, I don't see a button couldn't be added to the date indicator to do the same thing. https://askubuntu.com/questions/887799/launch-calendar-from-system-tray

Comment: Looks like there used to be a button in the date indicator to open the calendar, once upon a time: https://askubuntu.com/questions/69349/how-to-change-gnome-shell-calendar-default-application?rq=1

Comment: @guttermonk, the question of this post does not refer to opening a calendar app. It refers to the missing functionality of "click on calendar item@top bar" -> open default calendar's details about this calendar item".

Comment: I've gathered that by your response to my solution, but your question title says "How to make gnome-shell calendar open calendar app when clicking onto calendar entry?". So please forgive me if I thought you were interested in opening the calendar app from gnome-shell calendar like the question suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, this does not seem possible, because no API exists, that would allow gnomeshell to interact with events from e.g. evolution or gnome-calendar. see https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/issues/262#note_540721

For an issue that discussed this issue specifically, see https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/1297

Answer (score 0):

It's not very intuitive but if you click on a date in the calendar and then click on the date that pops up in the top left, it will open your default calendar app.

I tried clicking in the calendar, on the events, on the date in the top-right, etc. ...finally accidentally clicked on the right spot!

It doesn't open more details like you were looking for, but it does open the calendar. You can change your default calendar in **Settings > Details > Default Applications**. Hope this helps!

[image: gnome-shell calendar]

Comment: thanks, but the answer does not respond to the specific issue of the question. Please do add your voice to the issue discussed at https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/1297